# How to use Fetch queries in a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make a request to the server via a map with different urls, then I set the data in State and use it for output. I want the requests to be consecutive but sometimes they do not work correctly and get bugs, how to write the code for normal data retrieval?

```
const urlList = ["countries", "states", "cities", "users"];
componentDidMount() {
         urlList.map( (url, index) => {
            return servicesAPI.getResourse(url).then( (body) => {
                index !== 3 ?  this.setState({
                                 dataAPI : [...this.state.dataAPI, body] }) :
                                this.setState({
                                    dataAPI : [...this.state.dataAPI, body],
                                    loaded: true
                                })

            })
        })
export default  class ServicesAPI {
    _apiBase = `http://localhost:3001/`;


    async getResourse(url) {
        const res = await fetch(`${this._apiBase}${url}`);

        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${url}` +
                `, received ${res.status}`)
        }
        return await res.json();
    }
```

Comment: There are two await keyword inside getResource func. It should be only one.

Comment: not sure why you are using map to loop over the array since you are not using it to map anything.

Comment: Using promises? `var promises = []; urlList.forEach( function(element) { promises.push(yourRequest); }); Promise.all(promises).then(results => { ... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `Promise.all();`

```
componentDidMount() {
     const fetchPromises = [];
     urlList.forEach( (url, index) => {
        fetchPromises.push(servicesAPI.getResourse(url));
     });

     const allResourcesPromise = Promise.all(fetchPromises);
     allResourcesPromise.then(data => {
        // list with responses
     }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.toString());
     });

}
```

**Sample example:**
https://jsbin.com/vevufumano/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Also instead of then, where is possible, you can use async/await for more cleaner code.

Comment: "*I want the requests to be consecutive*" – Your code will run them in parallel.

Comment: I appreciate your highlight. The requests are consecutive, keeping its order.